# Please recommend some exercise on legs

Tags: legs

Some background: I'm doing push-ups now, around 100-200 push-ups a day, 2-3 times a week, each day i'll do it in around 4-5 groups, each group 40-50 push-ups.
I'm also doing plank, for the core muscles.

i'd like to do some work-out for build leg's muscle.

i hope it will not require additional equipment.

Also i hope it's not hurting the knee, as i'm approaching 40... preferable something like plank, that is static. I used to run, about 12 km in 1 hour, but it's a bit long and i heard running hurt the knee.

hope this question is valid to the forum. cheers.

Comment: If you are concerned about your knees, I believe the advice for squatting is to ensure that your knees do not jut forward over your feet while performing the movement. Stand with your face almost touching a wall (maybe 6 inches away), and then perform the squat. If your knees bump into the wall in front of you, your form is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several great workouts you can do at home to workout legs. Now, keep in mind, running is not so much about building leg muscle, but a more cardio related activity. I'm not saying you won't work the muscles, but most people don't run to build leg muscle.

Now, on to leg workouts. There are plenty of good body weight leg workouts out there and generally (in my experience) I've only ever had knee pain from weighted leg workouts (besides running). I'll keep that in mind when I recommend workouts though.

**Squats**

Squats are a great exercise for working legs. Keep in mind, they do sometimes cause knee problems, so if you start feeling pain STOP. Squats will work the quads.

[image]

**Lunges**

Lunges are another great leg exercise. They work glutes and hamstrings. Again, keep in mind, these may cause knee pain, but generally only with weight. STOP if you feel pain.

[image]

**Wall Sits**

A good stationary workout (that shouldn't cause any knee pain) would be wall sits. These are definitely not easy and will work quads.

[image]

[Click here for many more good leg workouts.](http://workoutdojo.com/bodyweight-exercise/bodyweight-leg-exercises/)

**Knee Pain**

Everyone is different when it comes to injuries. Some of these exercises may give you pain in your knees, while it may not for other people. The safest way to avoid injury is always maintain good form and if you feel any joint pain STOP what you are doing.

Comment: thanks! i saw wall sit in P90 videos (actually i tried it a few weeks but didn't finish, shame), i know it's challenging. also it's static and not taking much time. Good, i'll start from there :)

Answer (score 2):

-40 meter dash x 3 sets - take a 3 minute rest inbetween
-hill sprints for 30 seconds
-Power leap (from a full squat position, leap as high as you can, as far as you can for 15 reps) for 3 sets.

This can all be done outside.

Comment: @ghost-zfh thanks that's good work-outs in fresh air :)

Answer (score 1):

Squats, squats, squats, squats, squats, squats, squats, squats, squats.

Also, lunges and hill or stair sprints. But squats. Your desire for static exercises is wrong. Squat. It's good for your knees. Squat.

Comment: "Squat. It's good for your knees." Any resources to back this up?

Comment: @JordanCarroll Yes, but what exactly would lead you to think that moving a joint through its normal range of motion would be *bad*?

Comment: Which isn't to say that I disagree with the formulation in your answer--after all, any movement can cause injury--but the idea that squats are dangerous is ill-grounded. Pathology is dangerous; if you can't squat you have a problem you need to fix.

Comment: Haha, answering my question with a question isn't valid support of your claim. Only a fool would believe something without proof. So, where are these resources?

Comment: @JordanCarroll [Schoenfeld](http://general-stuff.38656.n3.nabble.com/file/n2911800/Squat_Depth.pdf) (PDF) is a good start, but you've put me in a bit of a prove-a-negative situation. What do you think is dangerous about squats other than having a preexisting issue?

Comment: I haven't exactly said I thought it was dangerous. That's what I've always heard. So, naturally, I was interested in finding out why you say it's "good for your knees."

Comment: @JordanCarroll History on the demonization of squats: "The Knee Is Not For Bending", the science of which has been discredited as Schoenfeld and [Beardsley](http://www.strengthandconditioningresearch.com/2012/08/13/how-are-partial-and-full-squats-different/) discuss. On the positive side (that is, to specifically support my claim), squats strength the muscles that support the knee, and are a "use it or lose it" movement. If you don't squat, then soon your knees (and hips, and ankles) will not be able to support you squatting. And then it *is* bad for you, but not out of any inherent quality.

Comment: Sorry, link: http://sportsillustrated.cnn.com/vault/article/magazine/MAG1073593/index.htm

Comment: @JordanCarroll - If you go to google scholar and type in "squat knee health" there are some studies on squats and knee biomechanics in both healthy and diseased state groups, as well as some rehab writeups.